# Android - How to cancel BottomNavigationView animation when pressing any item

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have been developing an app with Kotlin and I decided to use `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` to let the user navigate between the "main" activities.

The navigation between activities works fine, except that there is always that slide animation from right to left when a new activity starts.

I have tried

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
```

This stops the slide animation, but a new fade animation seems to be triggered (it fades fast, but it is like a fast flash from a camera).

I have also tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION`  when starting a new activity but it doesn't solve the problem either.

And finally I tried adding `<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>` to my app theme and once more the slide animation stops, but the fade animation is triggered.

What I want is to cancel any animation and simple load the new activity (all the apps I use seem to don't use any animation when an item from bottomnavigation is pressed).

I appreciate any help

**EDIT**

The use of multiple activities is intentional.

Comment: If you add more of your current code, someone might be able to help you better.  I don't have your issue, but I also have a single activity.

Comment: Right now I don't have any code related to the animations, it's doing the "default" slide right to left animation. The content of each activity are completely different (except the bottomnavigation of course). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
Are you sure that you want to use many activities for it instead of one with many fragments?

Is it intentional?

Comment: Yes it is intentional, I will edit it. Thanks!